# Why is the sample space for Bayes's rule P(B) when we are conditioning on event B certainly occurring?

Tags: statistics

Bayes's rule states $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)},$ where P(B) $\in [0,1].$ What I can't quite wrap my head around is why P(B) isn't equal to one. If we are conditioning on event B certainly happening, wouldn't the probability of event B happening be 1? I am also trying to understand this concept in terms of sample spaces, where P(B) would be the sample space for $P(A|B).$ What doesn't quite make sense about that either is that it seems $P(B)$ is still defined in the context of the larger sample space. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a continuous random variable, $A=\mathbb Q$ and $B=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$.  Probability zero doesn't mean that the event "can't happen".

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(B)$ is the "original" probability of $B$, before we condition. You are correct that the conditional probability $\mathbb{P}(B | B)$ is equal to $1$ but that's not the relevant probability.